# Display data from two tables with foreign key in Crystal Reports using C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, foreign-keys

I have two tables, **BonLivraison** and **LigneBonLivraison**:

**BonLivraison**: *CodeBonLivraison*, *DateBonLivraison*

**LigneBonLivraison**: *Id*, *Quantite*, *LibArticleAr*, *CodeBonLivraison* (Foreign key from BonLivraison table).

I used this code in order to display data from these two tables in Crystal Reports:

```
string sql3 = "SELECT BonLivraison.CodeBonLivraison, BonLivraison.DateBonLivraison, LigneBonLivraison.Quantite, LigneBonLivraison.LibArticleAr FROM BonLivraison, LigneBonLivraison WHERE BonLivraison.CodeBonLivraison = @numm AND MONTH(BonLivraison.DateBonLivraison) = @d1 AND BonLivraison.CodeBonLivraison = LigneBonLivraison.CodeBonLivraison";

SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(sql3, con);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numm", row);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue));
SqlDataAdapter dscmd3 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd3);

dscmd3.Fill(dsS, "BonLivraison");
dscmd3.Fill(dsS, "LigneBonLivraison");
CrystalReport6 objRpt6 = new CrystalReport6();
objRpt6.SetDataSource(dsS);

crystalReportViewer6.ReportSource = objRpt6;
```

But this code displays doubled data like this:

[image]

It should display just one record "HP S1933 MONITOR" and one record "CANON LIDE 110". I tried `INNER JOIN`, but had same problem, how do I solve this?

Comment: I've edited your question to improve the formatting, but I did not alter the code. Consider editing your question to put an `@` in front of your SQL string declaration and formatting the SQL to use multiple lines. This will greatly improve the readability of the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should only fill your dataset dsS once.

You are joining two tables, but end up still with one result set of data.

You also don't need to use that overload of Fill to specify a table. Just do:

```
dscmd3.Fill(dsS);
```

Comment: I tried this but i get the report empty without any data